# How many son(s) and daughter(s) did Vibhisana and Indrajit have?

Tags: ramayana, vibhishana, indrajit

Did Vibhisana have any son and daughter? and Did Indrajit have any son and daughter? Any mention in Ramayan?

Did Vibhisan have any son/daughter after marring Mandodari?

Comment: Vibhisan had a daughter named AnalTe.